# Re-rendering 2 different components but with same key (React)

Tags: reactjs

What would happen if I replace a react element in the component tree with an entirely new react element but both components have the same key? My understanding is that react reconciliation would cause a re-render however I'm confused on the reason for why. I thought that keys acts as a way of identification when comparing 2 elements. So if 2 different react elements share the same key, doesn't react consider them the same and not cause a re-render?

Comment: Re-rendering happens when the state of a component changes. Keys just act as ids for different components.

Answer (score 2):

> What would happen if I replace a react element in the component tree with an entirely new react element but both components have the same key?

If their type is different, then react will still unmount the old one, and mount the new one.

> however I'm confused on the reason for why.

I'm not sure how they could have designed it any other way. If i switch from an element `<Foo key={1}/>` to a `<Bar key={1}/>`, and both of those components have arbitrary state, i can't think of a way that you could transfer the state of the first component type into the second one, while still behaving in a predictable way. Well, there's one way: you could reset the state entirely, but that's basically unmounting/remounting.

Perhaps for native dom elements they could make it work, such as going from `<p key={1}/>` to `<div key={1}/>`, but it would be weird to have it work one way for native elements and another way for custom elements.

Comment: Oh. Wait so in that case, what would be the point of keys? If the react element type is always the one being compared (for whether to cause a re-render or not), then I feel like the only point of keys is to prevent re-renders wherein the types of the children are the same but their ordering is different. i.e. children can go from "<Foo key={1}/> <Bar key={2}/>" to "<Baz key={3}> <Foo key={1}/> <Bar key={2}/>" and there isn't a re-render of Foo and Bar

Comment: Keys aren't there to *prevent* unmounting, they're there to **cause** unmounting. If either the type or the key change, the component unmounts. The most common use of keys is for arrays, which are normally made of the same type of elements. With no keys, react would see that the types havn't changed and just update the props of the elements that already exist. With keys, it can unmount some and mount others. Keys are occasionally useful in cases that don't involve arrays, as a way to force a component to unmount/remount when normally it wouldn't.